# Minecraft mid-command delay for 1.15.2

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How do you put a delay in the middle of command?

I'm making a TNT run (without TNT) and my issue is, when you start TNT run and you start jumping, sometimes a command block will register the block under you and delete it, and sometimes it will happen even before you will jump again, so you will fall to another layer/void instantly without making a mistake.
Here is the command that I'm using:

```
/execute as @a[distance=..100] at @a[distance=..100] if block ~ ~-0.5 ~ cyan_terracotta run setblock ~ ~-0.5 ~ air
```

(command block  is "unconditional" and mode is "repeat (purple)")

All I want is just a delay; for example, half a second between "command block realised there is cyan_terracotta under player" and "setting block air under player" to let the player jump before falling down the layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it in one command, as far as I know. However, you can use a scoreboard objective to count the ticks that a player has been on `cyan_terracotta` for.

First create a dummy scoreboard objective: (I've called it `obj` here)

```
/scoreboard objectives add obj dummy
```

Then reset scores for players who aren't standing on cyan terracotta:

```
/execute as @a at @s unless block ~ ~-1 ~ cyan_terracotta run scoreboard players reset @s obj
```

Now increment the score for players who *are* on cyan terracotta:

```
/execute as @a at @s if block ~ ~-1 ~ cyan_terracotta run scoreboard players add @s obj 1
```

Then run your command at each player when it has been half a second:

```
0.5 seconds * 20 ticks per second
10 ticks
/execute as @a at @s if score @s obj matches 10.. run setblock ~ ~-1 ~ air
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i didnt expected answer so fast

Comment: If this answer helped you, mark it as accepted by clicking the tick mark (✓) on the left of the question.